# Fusebox invoking a fuse within the code

Tags: coldfusion, fusebox

Does anyone know if its possible to invoke a fuseaction within a coldfusion template?

Answer (score 3):

*(You haven't specified which Fusebox version; this answer applies to Fusebox 5.x)*

Your title and question is asking two different things - a fuse and a fuseaction are two distinct things. A fuse is simply a CFML template, whilst a fuseaction represents a bundle of logic that performs a particular action (similar to a function).

#### Fuses:

To invoke a fuse, simply **include** the file as you would normally - there's no special FB functionality required for this.

#### Fuseactions:

To invoke a fuseaction, use the **do** verb, like so:

```
<cfset myFusebox.do('circuit.fuseaction') />
```

To store the result, use the second argument for the content variable:

```
<cfset myFusebox.do('circuit.fuseaction',varname) />
```

This is the equivalent of this XML:

```
<do action="circuit.fuseaction" contentvariable="varname" />
```

There are other arguments available, see [**this Fusebox cheat sheet**](http://www.dopefly.com/projects/fuseboxxmlcheatsheet.cfm) which contains plenty of other useful info too.

Comment: Fuseactions is what I was looking for, and I will give your solution a try. Thanks I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

With MVC, you should be working through a single entry-point. So only a single fuseaction should be called during your request.

BUT that fuseaction can call some of the other model and view templates as needed. And I believe that Fusebox allows you to refactor that logic into something that can be used by multiple actions. (I'm a bit rusty on my Fusebox functionality though, but I bet some Googling will lead you the way.)

As a dire last resort, you could use `<cfhttp>` to call a URL within your app that invokes that fuseaction. But why not just run some of the code directly without needing to burden your server with another HTTP call?

Comment: _"So only a single fuseaction should be called during your request."_ - nope. There will be a single entry point, but it is perfectly valid (and encouraged) to divide the request up into further sub-fuseactions. There's even the ability to set prefuseaction and postfuseactions.

Comment: _"And I believe that Fusebox allows you to refactor that logic into something that can be used by multiple actions."_ I suppose the proper way to describe this was with a "prefuseaction." I think prefuseactions are a much more expressive way to run refactored controller logic, and it is in line with more modern development practices. (Think `before_filter` in Rails and `filters()` in CFWheels.)