# How to intercept and replace fuseaction content in Application.cfc?

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, fusebox

I use Coldfusion 9, fusebox 3 and an Application.cfc in my web application.
I would like to control, intercept and eventually change the value of fuseaction in the onRequestStart section of the Application.cfc

I'm able to check the content of the fuseaction ( with a single ListFirst(fuseaction, ".")) but I have tried to replace the fuseaction value without success.

Should I need to absolutely use a  and rebuild my URL or is there another solution ?

What is the best solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fusebox invoking a fuse within the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004014/fusebox-invoking-a-fuse-within-the-code)

Comment: " I have tried to replace the fuseaction value without success." Show us your code, and describe the results more thoroughly. Read this: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html, and the various docs it links to about how to ask questions.